# Slow down voice speed in Twlio (Japanese)

Tags: php, api, twilio, cjk

I'm working with Twilio for saying Japanese text, but Twilio say so fast and my customer can't hear it.

I read Twilio's document but not have option for voice speed.

I read some topic for add comma into the text, but say so slow.

Somebody can share me about solution? Thank you.

Comment: Ask Twilio customer service?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You may be interested to hear that [Twilio's text to speech](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech) now supports using AWS Polly and SSML to better control speech.

To control the rate at which the text is spoken you can use the [`<prosody>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#prosody). For example, to speak slower you would surround the text with `<prosody rate="slow">` tags. There is more documentation on how to use SSML in the [AWS docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#prosody).

Comment: Twilio prosody tag direct link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#prosody

Comment: Thanks, I don't think we had those docs when I wrote this! I'll update my answer.